# dbplyr bypasses indexes and runs sequential scan

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, odbc

I have a particular problem with respect to `dbplyr` performance when connecting to PostgreSQL.

Having tested with different packages (`RPostgres`,`RPostreSQL` and `odbc`), the latter summarises the performance issue.

This is `dbplyr` specific and doesn't occur with `dbGetQuery`.

Here are the steps I used

## Step 1: connection

```
odbc_driver <- if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
  "PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)"
} else {
  "PostgreSQL Unicode"
}

con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  Driver = odbc_driver,
  Server = pikachu_ip,
  Database = pikachu_db,
  UID = pikachu_user,
  PWD = pikachu_password,
  Port = 5432
)
```

## Step 2: run query with dbplyr

This is slow, takes around 5 minutes, and `show_sql()` reveals the same query from step 3.

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)

tbl(con, in_schema("pikachu", "stock")) %>% 
  filter(month == 201305) %>% 
  group_by(product) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  collect()
```

## Step 3: run query with dbGetQuery

This is fast and takes less than 2 seconds. I also checked that this uses the indexes (tested with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`).

```
odbc::dbGetQuery(con,
  'SELECT "product", COUNT(*) AS "n"
  FROM pikachu.stock
  WHERE ("month" = 201305)
  GROUP BY "product"'
)
```

Comment: Please share the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output for both, so we can know what happened